# Difference between Lucene and Zend Search Lucene

Tags: lucene, zend-search-lucene

Please is anyone know the difference between **Zend Search Lucene** and **Lucene**?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ZajimKujovic - you're arguing (in comments) that the answer @Niels gave  isn't good... But your question is not good either! Please correct it, and tell us exactly what kind of difference you're talking about instead of being sarcastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.search.lucene.overview.html):

Zend_Search_Lucene is a general purpose text search engine written entirely in PHP 5. Since it stores its index on the filesystem and does not require a database server, it can add search capabilities to almost any PHP-driven website. Zend_Search_Lucene supports the following features:

- Ranked searching - best results returned first
- Many powerful query types: phrase queries, boolean queries, wildcard queries, proximity queries, range queries and many others.
- Search by specific field (e.g., title, author, contents)

Zend_Search_Lucene was derived from the Apache Lucene project. The currently (starting from ZF 1.6) supported Lucene index format versions are 1.4 - 2.3. For more information on Lucene, visit http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but I had already read this. What interests me is the fundamental difference between these two...

Comment: It's right there in the text: it's a PHP5 port of the Java original. They're functionally mostly identical.

Comment: Well completely rewriting in another language isn't really a tiny difference, but apart from that, yes as the text states their indexes are even compatible.

Comment: I totally agree with you for rewriting into another language, but my primary goal isn't language in which zend search lucene or lucene is written, but search algorithms in both. Did these algorithms are same to both or is there exists some difference? But you already answered on my question :-) sorry if I'm not clearly defined my question...

Comment: The algorithms are supposed to be identical yes, it's for all intents and purposes the same product.

Comment: From what I understand, the Zend indexes are compatible with, and based on, Lucene 2.3.  There have been significant changes to Lucene since then, particularly in 4.x.  If they were identical before, seems unlikely that they are now.